# Convert latitude and longitude into meters or kilometers

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, mapkit, mkmapview

I have two MapKit annotations, displaying latitude and longitude.

Is there any way for me, through existing Objective-C iOS API functions to calculate the distance between the two?

Comment: In the general case, this is actually unsolvable.  Latitude and longitude are *angular* measurements, whereas meters and kilometers are *linear* measurements.  You can only convert between them if you (a) know the shape of the Earth (or geodetic datum) that was used to compute the latitude and longitude, and (b) are either using the great circle distance, or else have a projected coordinate system in which to perform the linear calculation.  A good place to start is the Wikipedia article on [geographic coordinate systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system).

Answer (score 17):

The [MapKit framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008209) contains many functions, and you will find `CLLocationDistance MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(MKMapPoint a, MKMapPoint b);` which returns the distance, in meters, between two points in the map. Maybe you could use it to solve your problem.

First create the two corresponding points, and the get the distance:

```
MKMapPoint p1 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coord1);
MKMapPoint p2 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coord2);
CLLocationDistance dist = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(p1, p2);
```

Answer (score 4):

`CLLocation` `distanceFromLocation` does the job.
It gives the greatcircle distance in meters between two `CLLocation`s.
I just tried and tested it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

What you need is the haversine forumla:  http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

[image: haversine]

From:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

You can find an Objective-C implementation here:  http://www.jaimerios.com/?p=39

Comment: Note, though, that the Haversine formula assumes the Earth shape is a perfect sphere, which is not very accurate.  Much better would be to use [Vincenty's formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae).

Comment: On the other hand, @Daniel, in some occasions both methods might be overkill. I once compared the 64-bit floating-point results of many formulas, including Haversine, with a much easier formula. Compared to Haversine (which indeed is not perfect either) for worldwide distances, errors could be as large as 7.4%. But within the Netherlands the maximum error was only 0.007% (or 15 meters). (Used to find the top-10 nearby stores. As this included a database lookup in a non-spatial database, limiting the number of trigonometric and geometrical functions made up for the larger error.)

Comment: (I never found any official name for this; with `R` the radius of the earth, and coordinates in decimal degrees just like Google Maps: `d = R * π/180 * sqrt( (lat2 - lat1)^2 + cos(lat1 * π/180) * cos(lat2 * π/180) * (lng2 - lng1)^2 )`. When not displaying the distance, so when just interested in the a *relative* ordering, then the calculation of the `sqrt` is not even needed.)

Answer (score 0):

This is called "great circle distance".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance